# Inverse of a product involving non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

I'd like to simplify the expression $$ (V' A V)^{-1} $$ where $V \in \Re^{n \times k}$, $n > k$ with $V'V = I$ and $\mathrm{rank}(V) = \text{rank}(V' A V) = k$. The $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is not symmetric but its inverse $A^{-1}$ is known.
Is it possible to get rid of the inverse by expressing $ (V' A V)^{-1} $ in terms of some product involving $ A^{-1}, V$ and $V'$?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1$ and $V=(1,0,\ldots,0)'$ we have $V'V=1$ and $$V'AV=a_{11}$$ The product is not invertible if $a_{11}=0.$ For example $n=2$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 1 &0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that $\text{rank} (V'AV) = k$ and have edited the question accordingly. However, the matrix $A$ from this example is symmetric. I'd suggest the following example instead: $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $V = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}$